# Autocomplete feature is not working when used in React in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Generally Autocomplete works in all browsers if turned on.
But for my React application it is not working in chrome and IE, whereas it is working in firefox.

what i am expecting from Autocomplete:

when user enters a value in input fields of forms it should save those values and show those values when the user again comes on the same field.
But in chrome it is working 3 times out of 5 times.

I have tried changing React controlled components to uncontrolled components using createRef(), this solution has worked for Firefox but not for chrome.

here is what my input looks like:

```
<input
       id={id}
       name={id}
       className="form-control"
       required={required}
       type={type}
       placeholder={placeholder}
       onChange={this.handleOnChange}
       ref={this.input}
     />
```

Comment: Im pretty sure that autocomplete is based on the input's `name` field. If that value is different every time, you won't get the same autocomplete.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)